# implementation of heuristics using C++ to solve operations research problems

Tags: cplex, combinatorial-optimization, algorithms, heuristics, implementation

can anyone suggest some good books with the implementation of heuristics and matheuristics using C++ to solve operations research problems especially routing problems such as TSP and VRP. also, I need to know how I can link c++ and cplex?

Comment: Just to ask the obvious, if you're primarily looking at routing problems have you considered just using existing open source solvers like Google's OR tools or jsprit instead? No point reinventing the wheel etc...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I design an algorithm for my problem, so l need to implement it myself.

Comment: Consider looking into open source implementations like [vroom](https://github.com/VROOM-Project/vroom) or [this one](https://github.com/alberto-santini/tsppddl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the last question (how to link C++ and CPLEX), CPLEX has a C++ API that is thoroughly documented in the user manual. They also provide quite a few C++ examples (source code).

Answer (score 6):

The best paper we ever read about the implementation of heuristics for the TSP is ["An Effective Implementation of the Lin-Kernighan Traveling Salesman Heuristic" by Keld Helsgaun](http://webhotel4.ruc.dk/%7Ekeld/research/LKH/LKH-2.0/DOC/LKH_REPORT.pdf). This 70-page report is really a masterpiece in the field. You can find more details [here](http://webhotel4.ruc.dk/%7Ekeld/research/LKH/) about Helgaun's research on TSP, and [here](http://webhotel4.ruc.dk/%7Ekeld/research/LKH-3/) for extensions to VRP.

You can also have a look at [our paper](https://www.localsolver.com/fgardi/downloads/Benoist-Estellon-Gardi-Jeanjean_TRSC_09_extended.pdf) on the Inventory Routing Problem, which describes a "mixed-variable" local search approach to deal with extensions of VRP involving additional quantitative decisions, constraints, and objectives.

**Disclosure:** LocalSolver is our commercial software product.